# Changing the default URL for a PhoneGap project

Tags: xcode, cordova

A PhoneGap project, by default, loads a local HTML page that's in the "www" folder. I want to replace the default page with an external URL. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is theoretically possible by modifying the AppDelegate.m file in your project then having your www/index.html file immediately redirect to an external URL via JavaScript.

**However**, the main reason it isn't all that easy to do is that if you *did* do this Apple would almost certainly reject it as either loading remote JavaScript or as being nothing more than a wrapper for a website (both reject-able offences).

Comment: I agree with devgeeks. If you can, I would stick with loading your html/js locally; but use ajax requests to talk to your web server.